# Parsing and retrieving form data from an XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, xmlhttprequest

I have a functionality wherein i submit the form data using ajax, XMLHttpRequest, to another jsp for processing and returning the appropriate response based on the parameters of the form data. Below is the code for it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  var form = document.forms.namedItem("userinfo");
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    var oData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("userinfo"));
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","sample.jsp",true);
  xmlhttp.send(oData);
  ev.preventDefault();}, false);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="userinfo">
  <label>Your email address:</label>
  <input type="email" autocomplete="on" autofocus name="userid" placeholder="email" required size="32" maxlength="64" /><br />
  <label>Your name:</label>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="on" autofocus name="username" placeholder="text" required size="32" maxlength="64" /><br /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

  <div id="myDiv">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the hindrance i face in achieving that is i do not know how to parse the XMLHttpRequest in jsp to retrieve FormData instance so that i can obtain the form parameters. So can someone tell me how do i retrieve formdata instance/ post parameters from XMLHttpRequest in the target jsp?

Comment: The same way you usually parse form data.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: @Quentin: Okay i will learn and correct it as i am just a beginner to coding html.. The same way? So i should use var oData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("userinfo")) in the jsp? if yes how do i retrieve the parameters from FormData instance? I am asking  because I have googled it around but couldn't find much resource on FormData api

Comment: The FormData API is a JavaScript API for sending form data. You don't use it to read form data that has been submitted to the server. You read it like you read a regular HTML form submission.

Comment: Okay i get it. Thanks. So i tried parsing the form data like 'request.getParameter("the paramname")' and printing it in the target jsp but it doesn't get printed. Am i doing anything wrong in retrieving the parms submitted using FormData instance to the target jsp??

Comment: Just want to say that it's strange that this genuine question from a good SO contributor (many gold, silver and bronze badges) has been effectively shunned. Could there be a tacit conspiracy to keep Node.js learners in the dark ?

Comment: @Trunk: May be mate ;) Thanks for your concern. Jfyi it's thymeleaf templating framework

Comment: Oh ! But maybe this Thymeleaf thing can handle JavaScript data structures.